# Replacing/edit the csv header

Tags: perl

Hey guys this i've got to replace a certain header colum with a new one note it's just the header not anything else in the CSV file

```
Naam,Functie,Functiecode,SMS,telefoonnr. 1,telefoonnr. 2,telefoonnr. 3,,overig
```

The header of my files.
and telefoonnr. 1,telefoonnr. 2,telefoonnr. 3

Have to be replaced with

```
telefoonnr1,telefoonnr2,telefoonnr3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Tie::Array::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Array::CSV)

```
use Tie::Array::CSV;
my $filename = '/path/to/file.csv';
tie my @file, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $filename;
$file[0] = ['Naam','Functie','Functiecode','SMS','telefoonnr1','telefoonnr2','telefoonnr3',,'overig'];
untie @file;
```

Comment: Always: `use strict; use warnings;`  [Tie::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File), which [Tie::Array::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Array::CSV) uses, can be [notoriously slow with large files](http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=1000412).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $newHeader = 'Naam,Functie,Functiecode,SMS,telefoonnr1,telefoonnr2,telefoonnr3,,overig';

while (<>) {
    $_ = "$newHeader\n" if $. == 1;
    print;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Hope this helps!